# Create excel macro to open .dat files and convert them to Fixed Width .dat files in excel

Tags: excel, fixed-width, vba

I am trying to take .dat files and convert them to fixed width .dat files.  When I use Macro Recorder it pops out this:

```
Sub Macro6()
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
        "G:\N5Baseline\E1 and E3 Neuroscan\header files\2026E1BEC-1hB.dat", Origin:= _
        437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(35, 1), Array(44, 1), Array(55, 1), Array(68, 1), Array(79 _
        , 1), Array(88, 1), Array(99, 1), Array(110, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    ChDir "C:\Users\admin\Desktop"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Filename1.txt", _
        FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

I would want to be able to run this macro on hundreds of files in the same folder.  I would want it to open up this .dat file, convert it to fixed width .dat file and then save it in the same folder.  I am not great with VB scripting, so be gentle if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to find the files you want:

```
Dim FName As String
FName = Dir("e:\0\a\*.dat")
Do While FName <> ""
    Debug.Print FName
    FName = Dir
Loop
```

Instead of Debug.print, put your code ... or call your procedure with parameter like:

```
Macro6 ("e:\0\a\", FName)
```

The new files shall be named:

```
Left(FName, Len(FName) - 3) & "txt"
```

After save, close the files

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: I currently have this coding but it does not like what's after<> "":  
    Dim FName As String
    FName = Dir("G:\test\*.dat")
    Do While FName <> ""
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=FName_
        Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array( _
        Array(0, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(35, 1), Array(44, 1), Array(55, 1), Array(68, _
        1), Array(79, 1), Array(88, 1), Array(99, 1), Array(110, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
        True
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= FName
        xlText, CreateBackup:=False
        FName = Dir
        Loop
End Sub

Comment: FName rerturn only the name of the file, not the path (2° code sample). if you don't change the extension you overwrite (3° code)...